# How can I get the index after the apply the subset() on a data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I selected a subset from a data set, how can I get the index from the subset?

For example my data set "df" looks like:

```
>df
  data  result
1    1    good
2    0    good
3    1     bad
4    0     bad
```

I applied the subset() on the "df", I got a new data set:

```
> df.mysubset <- subset(df, data == 0)
> df.mysubset
  data  result
2    0    good
4    0    bad
```

But, how can I get the index "2" and "4" from "df.mysubset", I mean, "(2, good), (4, bad)" ?

Comment: With the `df` the original data set you can achieve that with `which(df$data == 0)`. With the second data set you can achieve your goal with `row.names(df.mysubset)` because rows are two and asking R with the `which` won't give you 2 and 4 but 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my comment, I use it as an answer: With `df` as the original data set, you can achieve that with `which(df$data == 0)`. With the second data set you can achieve your goal with `row.names(df.mysubset)` because rows are two and asking R with the `which` won't give you 2 and 4 but 1 and 2.

Answer (score 2):

The 2 and 4 are the row names. You can use:

```
row.names(df.mysubset)
```